# the difference between multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Value and multiprocessing.Value in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ctypes

I read the documentation of multiprocessing.Value
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value

and the documentation of multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Value
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Value

but couldn't figure out what is the difference between them.
do anyone knows?
thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In python2.7 at least, `Value` is simply [a wrapper function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/__init__.py#L248) around `sharedctypes.Value`, so you'll only notice a difference if you are doing some sort of weird typechecking.

In python3.6, it looks like `Value` is still just a wrapper around `sharedctypes.Value`, but [it takes care of passing an appropriate context](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/context.py#L131).